# Prevent traffic correlation/timing attack

Tags: configuration, onion-services, security, censorship, attacks

When running a hidden service, should the operator run own entry guard?

Logic be that if the entry guard run by operator, no possible way for traffic correlation by malicious people. Traffic correlation requires the entry guard to correlate traffic to obtain IP of the hidden service.

Answer (score 0):

No, this doesn't prevent all possible traffic correlation attacks.

People can still perform traffic correlation attacks even if they don't own or operate the entry guard. As long as they have visibility of both ends of the connection.

See [Attacks On Onion Routing](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#AttacksOnOnionRouting) in the Tor Project FAQ.